# Correct way of subtracting a plane from a bigger plane

Tags: modeling

I have a pretty general question. I have encountered this problem several times now (I'm a beginner, by the way). In the case I had two diferent planes (just edges, not faces yet) in the same XZ coordinates and wanted to create a face for the bigger element, but leaving the smallest one blank, as it was a hole on the biggest one, how would you proceed? Which is the easiest or fastest way to do it? I'm adding some screenshots. Thank you on advance!

[image: First]
[image: Second]

Edit: Situation with knife project.

[image]

Comment: Probably easiest to use Knife Project, but you'll need to Fill the large plane first and move the octagon forward slightly in the Y direction. Then go to front view (numpad 1). With the large plane selected go into Edit mode, CTRL-click the octagon then Mesh > Knife Project and delete the new face from your large plane. There's a quick Blender Secrets video [here](https://www.youtube.com./watch?v=rnDzzHAWEHQ)

Comment: @JohnEason No no, it's one mesh in _Edit Mode_ and he starts with only edges, no faces... I wouldn't use _Knife Project_ then.

Comment: Ah mea culpa. I was thinking it was two objects (although you could seperate it into two... :^). In that case your answer is the best.

Comment: Thank you, guys, and sorry for my late reply! I tried both options, and they are what I was looking for. I have a couple of questions, though: in Gordon's option, is there a way to get rid of the diagonals that are left? Deleting or dissolving them, delete part of the mesh. I guess they won't bother me, anyway. John's option is cool and almost exactly what I was looking for. I didn't know this tool.  The problem is that the projection on the bigger plane is in a different Y position. Is that normal? Is there a way to create an exact projection? Thank you!

Comment: @Rant Well, no matter which version you use, creating faces between edges or using _Knife Project_, you will never get rid of all diagonal edges. If you only problem that they are not aligned with the axes, you could of course split the edges of the square and connect the inner circle only horizontally and vertically instead of diagonal. But nevertheless there will stay edges, because a hole cannot be surrounded by a single polygon without connection from the inner border to the outer border.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon. What I meant is that the resulting circle of using knife project is not completely aligned with the original circle (which I slightly moved in the Y axis, as @JohnEason suggested). I wonder why is that, because that tool seemed really interesting for making an object to be "casted", as a shadow, on another one. Anyway, what you said about a hole not being able to be surrounded by a polygon without connection was really useful, because it seems pretty basic, but I still didn't know that. So thank you. Anyway, my whole question came because I always try to work under the...

Comment: ...Under the premise that I shouldn't have any internal faces in my whole proyect. So, right now I am making a PSX model, and I need a circular button on the surface. If I just extrude the circunference I created and create a face for the extrusion, I still have a face in the bottom of the button, which is part of the surface plane. Now I don't know if that is "acceptable" or if I should delete that part of the surface. That's the origin of my question. I don't know if I made myself explained :/ Anyway, I will edit my question with a screentshot of the problem with knife project. Thank you!

Comment: Your objects need to be viewed "head on" (i.e: numpad 1, 3, or 7) when you use knife project or the cut will be offset as you've found. [This](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html#knife-project) is the Blender manual entry. With regard to your other question about leaving invisible faces, it's a good idea to delete them, partly to keep the number of faces as low as possible, and partly because they can cause distortion and shading issues particularly when using a mirror modifier.

Comment: I see! Thank you very much. That will be very useful, indeed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say the simplest way is this, when you're in *Edit Mode* with *Edge Select* like in your top screenshot:

1. Select the top edge of the square and the two top edges of the circle. Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill them.

[image: fill top edges]

2. Now do the same for the bottom three edges.

[image: fill bottom edges]

3. Repeat this for the left three edges and again for the right three edges. You don't need to select the new diagonal lines for that.

[image: fill side edges]

Of course you could do this by creating two faces instead of one, but I think the four faces version above gives better, cleaner geometry:

1. Select the top and side edges and press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill them.

[image: fill top and side edges]

2. Then select the bottom edges and press <kbd>F</kbd> again.

[image: fill remaining edges]